# material angular predefined dialog close button not working

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-material

I tried a lot of methods from some sources but still cannot solve the problem of the close button of the predefined html dialog of material angularjs. When I pressed the outside area of dialog, it can be closed normally.

The error message I get using [Batarang Angular](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) is **cancel is undefined**.

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
  $scope.showTermUseDialog = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: DialogController,
      contentElement: '#termUseDialog',
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      targetEvent: ev,
      clickOutsideToClose: true,
      scope: $scope,
      preserveScope: true
    });
  };

  function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.hide = function() {
      $mdDialog.hide();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
      $mdDialog.cancel();
    };
  }



});
```

Full code can view at here: 
http://codepen.io/skylee91/pen/xRoLXo

### Note:

If the angular material version is 1.1.0, the code run as expected. But currently I am using the latest stable build 1.1.1, the close button is not fire the `ng-click` event.

### Solution

1. There is no solution for version 1.1.1 stable release currently as 'Pre-rendered Dialogs will be not linked to any scope and will not instantiate a new controller.'
2. Currently I use angular template dialog to solve this issue.

Comment: You have to add scope and preservescope to the showTermUseDialog
`  $scope.showTermUseDialog = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      scope: $scope,
      controller: DialogController,
      contentElement: '#termUseDialog',
      targetEvent: ev,
      controllerAs: 'dialog',
      clickOutsideToClose: true,
      preserveScope: true
    });
  };`

Comment: "Pre-rendered Dialogs will be not linked to any scope and will not instantiate a new controller."
https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10184#issuecomment-269390999

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add scope and preservescope to the showTermUseDialog
`$scope.showTermUseDialog = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: DialogController,
      contentElement: '#termUseDialog',
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      targetEvent: ev,
      clickOutsideToClose: true,
      scope: $scope,
      preserveScope: true
    });
  };`

And also add a call to close in the html; `ng-click="close()"`

See plnkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/c1tCfQVMcyj7ZtKRiTOa?p=preview

Comment: I tried to use your code on my codepen. The close button is still not working. I noticed that you are referring the angular material with version of 1.1.0. If I change to version to 1.1.1, it still cannot be closed. However, the close button is working for version 1.1.0. So weird !!!

Comment: Yes, you are right. With version 1.1.1 it fails silently, it might be because of this change. I'll maybe file a bug there.
https://github.com/angular/material/pull/9303